# class method TypeError "Int object not callable"

Tags: python, typeerror

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
class Car():    

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """initialize attribuites to describe a car"""
        self.make = make 
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
        self.increment_odometer = 0

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """
        Set the odometer reading to the given value. 
        Reject the change if it attempts to roll the odometer back.
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You cannot roll back the odometer.") 

    def read_odometer(self):
        """print at statement which shows the car's miles"""
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " " + "miles on it.")

    def get_descriptive_name(self):   
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()


    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        self.odometer_reading += miles      


my_old_car = Car ('subaru', 'outback', 2013)
print (my_old_car.get_descriptive_name())

my_old_car.update_odometer(23500)
my_old_car.read_odometer()

my_old_car.increment_odometer(100)
my_old_car.read_odometer()
```

Output:

```
2013 Subaru Outback
This car has 23500 miles on it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cars.py", line 42, in <module>
    my_old_car.increment_odometer(100)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have a method and an attribute of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you define a name for an increment_odometer object in the `__init__` and later define a method with the same name. Just remove the `self.increment_odometer = 0` in the `__init__`

```
class Car():

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """initialize attribuites to describe a car"""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0
        # self.increment_odometer = 0 ----> remove this line

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        """
        Set the odometer reading to the given value.
        Reject the change if it attempts to roll the odometer back.
        """
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You cannot roll back the odometer.")

    def read_odometer(self):
        """print at statement which shows the car's miles"""
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " " + "miles on it.")

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        """Add the given amount to the odometer reading."""
        self.odometer_reading += miles


my_old_car = Car ('subaru', 'outback', 2013)
print (my_old_car.get_descriptive_name())

my_old_car.update_odometer(23500)
my_old_car.read_odometer()

my_old_car.increment_odometer(100)
my_old_car.read_odometer()
```

Comment: Thank you, Bruno! I appreciate all the help for beginning programmers like myself.

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure will get the hang of it. Your style of programming looks good and learning classes is super important. If you want please can you mark question as answered. Thanks.