# Override setter with property: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop, properties, getter-setter, super

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../TEST.py", line 34, in <module>
    b.level = 12    # Error
  File ".../TEST.py", line 23, in level
    super().level(self, new_level)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

And here is the code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._level = 0

    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level

    @level.setter
    def level(self, new_level):
        self._level = new_level

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @property
    def level(self):
        return self._level

    @level.setter
    def level(self, new_level):
        super().level(self, new_level)



a = A()
print(a.level)  # --> 0
a.level = 12
print(a.level)  # --> 0

b = B()
print(b.level)  # --> 12
b.level = 12    # Error
print(b.level)  # never reached
```

I saw that post [class method TypeError "Int object not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58723090/class-method-typeerror-int-object-not-callable) but it did not help me

Comment: The reason is `super().level `is not a function.

Comment: Note, there's an open issue regarding `super` and `property`/descriptor setters: https://bugs.python.org/issue14965

Comment: DustyPosa, but it should be a function. I have written the same thing in another class and it works well. What code lines should I change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another answer seems to be the best one:

```
class B(A):
    @A.level.setter
    def level(self, new_level):
        super(B, type(self)).level.fset(self, new_level)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python properties are non-polymorphic :
https://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=122&thread=153649

Comment: Thanks I see now what is the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

The best I have come up is this:

1. If there is no need to override the getter then you can **prefix** by parent class name
2. **No code in setter**: setters only call other methods

   2.a Defined instance methods which do the setter instructions

   2.b Which are called by the setters

   ```
   class A:
       def __init__(self):
           self._level = 0

       def A_level_setter(self, new_level):      # 2.a
           print('Setter instructions of A')
           self._level = new_level

       @property
       def level(self):
           return self._level

       @level.setter
       def level(self, new_level):
           self.A_level_setter(new_level)        # 2.b

   class B(A):
       def B_level_setter(self, new_level):      # 2.a
           print('Setter instructions of B')
           self.A_level_setter(new_level)

       @A.level.setter                           # 1.
       def level(self, new_level):
           self.B_level_setter(new_level)        # 2.b

   class C(A):
       pass


   a = A()
   print(a.level)  # 0
   b = B()
   print(b.level)  # 0
   c = C()
   print(c.level)  # 0


   a.level = 1     # Setter instructions of A
   print(a.level)  # 1

   b.level = 2     # Setter instructions of A
                   # Setter instructions of B
   print(b.level)  # 2

   c.level = 3     # Setter instructions of A
   print(c.level)  # 3
   ```